# Is there a method of assigning markdown (or LaTex) text to a named variable or alias for repeated insertion into a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, markdown

I am making personal notes using markdown and LaTeX within a Jupyter notebook. Ideally I would like to handle recurring Latex expressions in the editor using a shorthand alias or token.  These tokens would then be substituted with the associated LaTeX expression on rendering the document.

For example, the following markdown ...

```
The Pauli X matrix is given by the following expression:
$ S_x =\frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $
```

...could be represented with the alternative but equivalent expression below in which the `spinX` alias is `{{dereferenced}}` having been defined elsewhere to be equal to the cumbersome `\frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}` expression.

```
The Pauli X matrix is given by the following expression:
$ S_x = {{spinX}} $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> New LaTeX macros may be defined using standard methods, such as `\newcommand`, by placing them anywhere between *math delimiters* in a Markdown cell. These definitions are then available throughout the rest of the IPython session.
>
> — https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebook.html

At the beginning of the document, put

```tex
$\newcommand{\spinX}{\frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}$
```

in a markdown cell. After that, you can use `\spinX` to use the alias in subsequent cells.

```tex
The Pauli X matrix is given by the following expression:
$S_x = \spinX$
```

[image: Screenshot]